# Ways to make money off land without selling, leasing, developing, or farming?

Tags: real-estate, land

What are some ways a company might make money off of land, other than selling or leasing it to tenants?

I'm trying to solve a bit of a weird business puzzle. Part of it involves a person who says he has a company that buys land which is very profitable, but he does not sell, lease, or develop on it. I asked if his company perhaps farms the land, but he said no to that as well. He said they have some way of making money off the land itself.

Comment: Sounds like a scam if there is a person trying to get you to spend money on land for them to make money off of.  If somehow legitimate, exploiting the minerals or selling mineral rights and just plain speculation (hoping the land will increase in value) are ways to do this.

Comment: @Eric Oh, ha no it's not a scam, there's no outgoing money involved and I was connected with them via a government/university program. Just a business network through my alma mater where they like to play some games. Mineral rights are interesting. It's based in Kansas, I will have to see if they have much mining there, thank you. (Update - I am seeing some Internet results on that topic in Kansas - thanks!).

Comment: I have seen a case of a small income from land because of advertising on it, the primary objective being land speculation.

Comment: Kansas - does the plot have a history of being farmed? It may be eligible for farm bailouts based on historical yield even if not currently being farmed (and if this were my business model, I would be shamed to explain to casual acquaintances that I am in essence a vulture capitalist welfare queen) https://www.fsa.usda.gov/news-room/news-releases/2019/usda-announces-details-of-support-package-for-farmers

Comment: @LorenPechtel Interesting, thank you. It's probably not enough to explain the level of income (high 6 to low 7 digits per year) but that could be a component of it at least.

Comment: @user662852 That's funny, I should've remembered to mentioned that I asked the same thing. I didn't realize they still had those programs these days. When I asked (as a joke) he said no. Whatever it is, it's some business that he's able to teach other people how to replicate upon securing the necessary bank financing.

Comment: @Eric Do you want to make "mineral rights" into an answer? That was a good one.

Comment: You're talking to a scammer, ghost them

Comment: "buys land which is very profitable" How is the land profitable before buying and why would someone sell it if there exist way to get profit without doing anything? Apart from scam I think of oscillator based on value of the land that rise with loans taken on that land "for future development".

Comment: You could operate a business of your own on the land.

Comment: "it's some business that he's able to teach other people how to replicate upon securing the necessary bank financing." Somehow I expect he makes more from "teaching" people than whatever he's doing with the land

Comment: @Kat It’s free. That’s why you have to solve the mystery and jump thru many hoops to get in. It’s like a university-approved club type of deal.

Comment: @Hack-R I hope you're right, but please keep your wits about you in case this takes a turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is exploiting, leasing or selling the mineral rights for the land.

Comment: In addition to being a valid answer, I've become 85% certain this is the answer to my puzzle! It fits perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

For the conditions given, a person can make profit out of land by some options:

- putting billboards
- putting cellphone towers
- putting solar panels and sharing the electricity with local electricity company
- Allowing Vehicles to park during office hours and charge for parking
- Allowing to park RV as camp site
- Allowing to put a tent for an event for specific hours
- Allowing mobile restrooms to be put for an event and move them post the event

**UPDATE**

- If there are trees in the land already, we can sell off the fruits from the tree and make money
- If there are trees in the land already, we can cut them off and make profit
- If the land is a green pasture, we can leave the land for cattle grazing and make money
- If there are trees in the land, if possible, we can put tree house and rent them
- If there are water sources like pond, we can allow kayaking in the pond

Comment: I'd consider any of these options to be forms of leasing the land.

Comment: Or developing it. They all involve putting something *on* the land.

Comment: @ThePhoton, I get your point. But, we are not leasing the land completely. We have control over the land and Putting these to take advantage of land space.

Comment: @chepner, These are temporary structures and land is not leased. We have more control over the land. I get your point. there is some development effort.